# Makefile evaluation question - foreach list doesnt evaluate before execution

Tags: shell, foreach, makefile, gnu

Here's a snippet from a Makefile which in my environment is recursive and it appears this piece of code has a n issue and I don't understand why foreach doesn't evaluate. The variables TOOLVERSION and TOOLSDIR are assigned values based on running a Ruby script. These provide the include paths for the C_FLAGS. The target test2 produces the right result where every element of C_FLAGS seperated by space appears on a new line which is the desired result. However test1 does not evaluate TOOLVERSION and TOOLSDIR so produces garbage. If I use $(shell getenvval.rb version) for assigning TOOLVERSION and TOOLSDIR the foreach work but the value of running the script is incorrect. I thought this was because something defined in the Makefile environment doesn't get to the shell so I used export but it didn't make a difference.

So the question comes down to why does the following foreach loop not work:

```
@$(foreach flag, $(C_FLAGS), `echo  $(flag) >> $(FILE_C1_LIST)`)
```

while this works:

```
@echo $(C_FLAGS) >> $(FILE_C2_LIST)
```

Appreciate any help in understanding the evaluation.

Snippet from Makefile:

```
export 


TOOLVERSION:= `getenvval.rb version`
TOOLSDIR:=  `getenvval.rb directory`

FILE_C1_LIST := test_c1.f
FILE_C2_LIST := test_c2.f

C_FILES =\
./a.c            \
./b.c             

C_FLAGS := \
-I$(TOOLSDIR)/$(TOOLVERSION)/tools/include \
-I./aa/include \
-I./bb/editline \
-g -DDEBUG   -DPLISIM -DINCLUDE_EDITLINE -DSYS_UNIX 

$(FILE_C1_LIST): $(C_FILES) 
    rm -f $(FILE_C1_LIST) 
    touch $(FILE_C1_LIST) 
    @(echo $(C_FLAGS) )
    @$(foreach flag, $(C_FLAGS), `echo  $(flag) >> $(FILE_C1_LIST)`)
    @$(foreach file, $(C_FILES), `echo $(file) >> $(FILE_C1_LIST)` ) 

$(FILE_C2_LIST): $(C_FILES) 
    @rm -f $(FILE_C2_LIST) 
    @touch $(FILE_C2_LIST) 
    @echo $(C_FLAGS) >> $(FILE_C2_LIST) 
    @$(foreach file, $(C_FILES), `echo $(file) >> $(FILE_C2_LIST)` ) 



test1:  $(FILE_C1_LIST)

test2: $(FILE_C2_LIST)
```

Comment: Putting a `@` in front of the command you are attempting to debug is supremely misdirected. Probably don't put it back when you're done (use `make -s` if you want it to run quietly).

Comment: RE `@`: maybe consider: http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Comment: You appear to be imagining that the `foreach` function will _execute_ the commands you are giving it, somehow.  That's not what it does.  `foreach` is a _text modification_ tool.  After the `foreach` completes, it evaluates to the result of that expansion.  It won't actually try to _execute_ any shell operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are odd. You appear to try to use shell syntax in constructs which are not going to be evaluated by a shell; and even if they were, the expressions would not be syntactically valid.

Without delving too much into the details, try this instead.

```
    printf '%s\n' $(C_FLAGS) >> $(FILE_C1_LIST)
```

In some more detail, your loop would create the text

```
    `echo one >>file` `echo two >>file` `echo three >>file`
```

where the backticks imply that the output from `echo` should be the text of a command which you want the shell to execute; but of course, because of the redirection, there is no output to standard output from any of these commands. (The superficial problem of having all the commands on a single line could be worked around with a semicolon after each.)

As a further aside, there is no need to `rm` or `touch` a file you are going to overwrite. Just write it. Your recipes can be substantially simplified.

```
$(FILE_C1_LIST): $(C_FILES)
    printf '%s\n' $(C_FLAGS) $(C_FILES) >$@

$(FILE_C2_LIST): $(C_FILES) 
    echo $(C_FLAGS) >$@
    printf '%s\n' $(C_FILES) >>$@
```

The parentheses you had around the first `echo` would needlessly run that in a separate subshell. I'm guessing you had that purely to see what you were doing; removing the `@` on your recipes does that much better. You can run `make` silently witth `make -s` once you have everything debugged and sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The printf works but I was hoping there was a way to make foreach work and as you indicated because of the redirection it doesnt get evaluated unless I have a ";" between the commands but I dont think the foreach syntax would allow it.

Comment: Why not? `$(foreach flag,$(C_FLAGS),echo $(flag) >>$(FILE_C1_LIST);)`

Comment: Tried that but it doesnt evaluate C_FLAGS and $flag comes out as the command itself that was used to evaluate TOOLSDIR and TOOLVERSION

Comment: Works for me ([demo](https://ideone.com/bZYous)); but trust me, the `printf` approach is better.